# next greater element in array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

void printNextGreaterElement(int input[], int inputSize) {
    stack<int> s;
    s.push(input[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < inputSize; i++) {
        while (!s.empty() && s.top() < input[i]) {
            cout<<"Next greater element for "<<s.top()<<"\t = "<<input[i]<<"\n";
            s.pop();
        }
        s.push(input[i]);
    }
    while (!s.empty()) {
        int top = (int) s.top();
        s.pop();
        cout<<"Next greater element for "<<top<<"\t = null\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    int input[] = { 98, 23, 54, 12, 20, 7, 27 };
    printNextGreaterElement(input, 7);
    return 0;
}
```

I was learning about NGE in the array and came across this piece of code which I found on geeksforgeeks and other websites, but isn't this gives wrong output for the test case:

14 
10 3 12 4 2 9 13 0 8 11 1 7 5 6

Comment: the implementation is perfectly correct, I think you are facing problem in understanding the definition of next greater element, I guess

Comment: you should include what you expect in question. and what you get from program.

Comment: but the output should be sequential as the order of numbers in the question?

Answer (score 0):

> Given an array, print the Next Greater Element (NGE) for every element. The Next greater Element for an element x is the first greater element on the right side of x in array.

Your code seems to be fine and gives the correct output of the input which you told gives wrong output is as following.

The input is as you mentioned

```
14 
10 3 12 4 2 9 13 0 8 11 1 7 5 6
```

The output is

```
Next greater element for 3       = 12
Next greater element for 10      = 12
Next greater element for 2       = 9
Next greater element for 4       = 9
Next greater element for 9       = 13
Next greater element for 12      = 13
Next greater element for 0       = 8
Next greater element for 8       = 11
Next greater element for 1       = 7
Next greater element for 5       = 6
Next greater element for 6       = null
Next greater element for 7       = null
Next greater element for 11      = null
Next greater element for 13      = null
```

For example, the second element in the array is `3`, the next greater element in the array is `12` (Which is the output).
The explanation of the algorithm is not given here as it is well written in the [post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/) you mentioned.